# stripe connect direct charge with intents

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to develop a direct charge flow with stripe-connect

According to [this](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#creating-paymentmethods-directly-on-the-connected-account) documentation they state that I need to add the connected_account_id when I initialize stripe on the client:

```js
// Set the connected Stripe Account on which the PaymentMethod should be created
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxx', {
  stripeAccount: "{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}" // ???
});

stripe.createPaymentMethod('card', cardElement, {
  billing_details: {
    name: 'Jenny Rosen',
  },
}).then(function(result) {
  // Handle result.error or result.payment_method
});
```

Is there any other way to do this without involving the client-side?
This was not the case for me when I was using `charges` API, but now with `intents` it seems like I have to do this? It seems very strange that I need to initialize stripe with a connected_customer as its possible that there are more than 1 connected_accounts, but they want me to set it in initialization of the library

In [another](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges) documentation of direct-charge they don't even mention the client-side requirement and they directly say:

> To directly charge on the connected account, perform a standard create
>   charge or create PaymentIntent request using your platform’s secret
>   key while authenticated as the connected account:

With this **serverside** code sample:

```js
stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  amount: 1000,
  currency: 'eur',
}, {
  stripe_account: '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
}).then(function(paymentIntent) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

As if this is enough, but its not working by itself because I get `no such payment method`

I also found this little piece of information -

> When directly charging on the connected account, you can provide a
>   token created using either your platform’s or the connected account’s
>   publishable key. (You can also use a shared customer to create a
>   token.)

Answer (score 3):

PaymentMethods have to be created on the account where they will be used. If you're a platform using Stripe Connect and you're creating charges directly on the connected account then the PaymentMethod has to exist on that connected account.

There are 2 approaches you can take here. You can either create the PaymentMethod directly on the connected account or you can create it on the platform and later share it to the connected account.

The former approach is the simplest. When you collect card details client-side, you use Elements. You can initialize it with the connected account's id directly in the `stripeAccount` option. That's the doc you found which lives [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#creating-paymentmethods-directly-on-the-connected-account).

Otherwise, you can create the PaymentMethod on the platform. Then, server-side, when the PaymentMethod is created, you can then *clone it* to the connected account. This is as simple as creating a new PaymentMethod from the existing one and you don't need their card details. This is documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#shared-payment-methods). Note that this only works for Card PaymentMethods.

For completeness, Card Tokens worked on the platform and connected accounts indifferently. This made the integration look a bit easier at first because you just created the token with the platform's key and then used it on the connected account. This only worked for cards and bank accounts though and can't work with other types of payment methods such as SEPA Debit for example or ACH Credit Transfer. Those require details about the account receiving the funds and have to always be created on the right account. PaymentMethods allow you to avoid this issue by requiring that you integrate it properly from the start.

Comment: As For the second option (shared paymentMethod) - I've tried that, but it does not work for the cases of SCA with 3D secure, because then on the server I get a secret, I pass that to the client and it fails with "no such payment intent". Because there is another step, my only solution is to pass `stripeAccount` when I initialize stripe on the client